# Wordpress excerpt element vanishing randomly

Tags: wordpress

I have no idea why but every 5-10 times I refresh my site in Chrome, all excerpts for each post on the home page vanish and there's just white space where they are supposed to be.

When I inspect in chrome, the `<p>` elements appear to be there but they just aren't showing up in the browser.

I have no idea what to do or even how to make the error appear consistently but it's freaking me out!

Any ideas would be deeply appreciated :)

An illustration is available at https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeqbO.jpg
and the site is at http://www.unleashreality.com/

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome. I tried thirty+ refreshes. Have you tried disabling plugins? When you inspect what is the CSS? Perhaps you are ending up with white text on a white background?

Comment: ...okay just happened again. i've noticed that once it does it and the excerpt is hidden, if i press f5 repeatedly it just keeps showing it as hidden but if i press cntrl+f5 to clear the cache then it shows up fine. spooky :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't see them the first time I visited, or any other time for that matter, so that's definitely a problem. I fixed it by removing `overflow: hidden` on the style:

```
div.excerpt-block {
    padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Of course, I'm browsing on Chrome Canary 18, so it's not entirely stable, but maybe that's an advantage. If it works in other browsers, file a WebKit or Chromium bug report.

Comment: ahhh forgot to fix that thanks for pointing that out. i think you're right because no vanishing excerpts so far (hitting f5 like mad). hopefully that's fixed it. thanks for taking a look :)